# function to count the number of loops in data and group them in r

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, group-by

I have cyclic data that forms loops in the data, as provided in the sample dataframe `df`:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Actuator.Force = c(-4853.5854, -4566.9771, -4198.7612, 
-3774.5527, -3317.6958, -2847.5229, -2364.7585, -1880.9485, -1405.4272, 
-930.289, -467.04822, -18.867363, 421.17499, 838.86719, 1239.9121, 
1626.0669, 1990.6389, 2334.0852, 2655.344, 2962.0227, 3243.7817, 
3506.2249, 3744.2622, 3959.8271, 4156.7061, 4324.9048, 4469.229, 
4591.6689, 4687.4194, 4764.0801, 4814.6167, 4840.313, 4846.0181, 
4826.3135, 4777.6553, 4696.0791, 4583.854, 4442.457, 4272.5254, 
4076.7224, 3851.1211, 3603.1853, 3330.7456, 3038.3157, 2724.115, 
2386.5476, 2032.5809, 1660.0547, 1268.0084, 859.16675, 432.4075, 
-14.131592, -479.29309, -955.67108, -1444.614, -1937.2562, -2437.0085, 
-2941.8914, -3450.9009, -3959.9597, -4468.9795, -4981.2549, -5492.6997, 
-6002.334, -6510.5425, -7016.2432, -7517.8286, -8013.1348, -8500.4199, 
-8974.8867, -9439.5479, -9890.5938, -10326.367, -10744.421, -11147.754, 
-11534.83, -11902.651, -12248.997, -12577.919, -12885.458, -13172.309, 
-13441.554, -13691.502, -13922.634, -14127.116, -14305.272, -14458.267, 
-14582.934, -14685.274, -14758.539, -14806.058, -14830.719, -14836.625, 
-14822.204, -14773.916, -14700.484, -14597.968, -14469.834, -14312.099, 
-14126.422, -13915.136, -13676.505, -13412.388, -13120.703, -12807.961, 
-12473.883, -12115.751, -11740.082, -11342.633, -10929.945, -10502.158, 
-10062.869, -9611.8271, -9146.6006, -8673.3545, -8191.7417, -7700.769, 
-7200.9346, -6695.8809, -6185.2378, -5670.8711, -5154.9995, -4643.4414, 
-4135.0015, -3629.2859, -3125.657, -2626.541, -2134.0662, -1646.4242, 
-1168.816, -699.63068, -245.34488, 192.7984, 618.76703, 1033.223, 
1428.922, 1807.2645, 2165.6274, 2507.6655, 2826.2754, 3120.4724, 
3395.2593, 3647.6946, 3879.4983, 4086.3855, 4265.1323, 4421.6831, 
4554.3594, 4657.8184, 4736.9561, 4792.6724, 4822.3784, 4830.3091, 
4815.9038, 4773.9692, 4706.4736, 4614.8379, 4491.3198, 4337.8892, 
4158.002, 3949.3147, 3713.4622, 3453.9114, 3167.8179, 2861.2598, 
2536.3259, 2187.3623, 1822.752, 1437.5449, 1034.8208, 617.23962, 
183.35637, -270.79733, -738.95618, -1220.1345, -1710.7787, -2206.1941, 
-2706.4871, -3210.8625, -3721.0002, -4233.6387, -4747.7271, -5258.7578, 
-5771.3071, -6280.7759, -6791.0166, -7295.0229, -7794.4199, -8287.4189, 
-8771.6377, -9243.3457, -9702.2559, -10146.865, -10577.053, -10989.863, 
-11385.981, -11760.477, -12116.938, -12456.351, -12772.688, -13071.995, 
-13349.56, -13611.837, -13852.025, -14066.192, -14254.534, -14420.322, 
-14556.846, -14668.379, -14753.795, -14815.698, -14857.507, -14872.669, 
-14865.908, -14836.117, -14774.959, -14686.203, -14569.189, -14426.374, 
-14253.839, -14054.1, -13825.626, -13570.092, -13290.482, -12987.772, 
-12664.012, -12316.427, -11948.471, -11560.391, -11154.085, -10733.564, 
-10299.443, -9853.6875, -9396.6436, -8925.8535, -8443.9336, -7956.8374, 
-7458.6333, -6954.7061, -6445.8086, -5929.9316, -5419.6182, -4908.4502, 
-4398.2227, -3885.9087, -3379.0095, -2874.7212, -2376.6907, -1884.6035, 
-1400.1414, -926.74658, -463.98688, -15.092632, 421.02869, 838.7132, 
1241.4564, 1630.713, 1999.5801, 2349.6597, 2678.7043, 2986.6536, 
3271.0425, 3535.8906, 3775.0059, 3991.6484, 4185.4834, 4354.6094, 
4495.666, 4610.7051, 4702.4521, 4770.9893, 4813.6733, 4832.2402, 
4830.335, 4802.6479, 4745.7451, 4660.7607, 4547.5942, 4406.2202, 
4236.4312, 4036.448, 3812.7585, 3562.6196, 3288.6797, 2993.6304, 
2673.9656, 2336.5691, 1977.1057, 1605.335, 1214.9467, 806.66827, 
380.42252, -62.247063, -522.36572, -996.21539, -1477.8905, -1969.7305, 
-2469.0476, -2971.5452, -3479.3577, -3992.8628, -4506.252, -5025.1992, 
-5545.3721, -6064.1323, -6576.875, -7086.855, -7590.6704, -8085.0815, 
-8567.9775, -9043.2002, -9507.4824, -9958.1904, -10392.594, -10814.161, 
-11215.28, -11600.177, -11967.055, -12312.813, -12642.992, -12948.593, 
-13238.12, -13509.343, -13760.307, -13987.689, -14191.591, -14364.724, 
-14514.282, -14638.64, -14738.083, -14811.377, -14862.124, -14888.534, 
-14893.003, -14876.485, -14828.384, -14752.178, -14650.495, -14518.901, 
-14358.499, -14171.098, -13956.202, -13714.101, -13446.276, -13151.266, 
-12836.099, -12495.902, -12137.276, -11756.888, -11357.116, -10942.688, 
-10514.518, -10073.99, -9619.6875, -9154.2783, -8679.9385, -8195.3867, 
-7699.6299, -7196.3784, -6689.6313, -6176.3032, -5664.7334),
Rotation = c(-0.005985651, -0.00565783616666667, -0.00522075016666667, 
-0.0046743925, -0.00406732866666667, -0.00343598223333333, 
-0.00286534205, -0.00219757165, -0.00156622503333333, -0.000934878566666667, 
-0.000267108158333333, 0.000303531998333333, 0.00084988955, 
0.0013962471, 0.00193046351666667, 0.00242825596666667, 0.00288962463333333, 
0.0033995583, 0.0038366445, 0.00424944783333333, 0.004637969, 
0.0050507725, 0.005378587, 0.00565783616666667, 0.00594922716666667, 
0.00620419383333333, 0.006410596, 0.0065684325, 0.00670198666666667, 
0.00683554116666667, 0.0069205295, 0.00699337683333333, 0.0070055185, 
0.006993377, 0.00696909483333333, 0.00688410516666667, 0.006774834, 
0.00659271483333333, 0.006386313, 0.00613134633333333, 0.0058399555, 
0.0055364235, 0.00518432633333333, 0.00483222916666667, 0.0044072845, 
0.00403090483333333, 0.00353311216666667, 0.0029988961, 0.00251324506666667, 
0.0020275938, 0.00144481233333333, 0.00086203085, 0.000303531998333333, 
-0.000315673273333333, -0.000983443666666667, -0.00162693151666667, 
-0.00233112578333333, -0.0029988961, -0.00366666666666667, 
-0.00433443683333333, -0.00496578316666667, -0.00563355366666667, 
-0.0062770415, -0.0069690945, -0.0076611475, -0.00836534183333333, 
-0.00902097083333333, -0.00968874116666667, -0.0103443703333333, 
-0.0109514346666667, -0.011594922, -0.012177704, -0.0127969093333333, 
-0.0133918318333333, -0.0139746131666667, -0.0145209698333333, 
-0.014982339, -0.0154437081666667, -0.0159050765, -0.0163178798333333, 
-0.0167185421666667, -0.0170706398333333, -0.0174105943333333, 
-0.0177505506666667, -0.018017659, -0.0182483433333333, -0.0184547455, 
-0.0186490056666667, -0.0187704183333333, -0.01887969, -0.0189525386666667, 
-0.018988962, -0.0190011033333333, -0.018988962, -0.0189768206666667, 
-0.0189282553333333, -0.0188189838333333, -0.018673289, -0.018442604, 
-0.0182240605, -0.017993377, -0.0176534206666667, -0.0173256068333333, 
-0.0169492263333333, -0.0165485635, -0.0161357608333333, 
-0.0156622516666667, -0.0152373058333333, -0.0147152313333333, 
-0.0141931568333333, -0.0136103748333333, -0.0130275935, 
-0.0123962468333333, -0.0118013235, -0.0112064015, -0.0105507718333333, 
-0.00993156683333333, -0.0092637965, -0.008620309, -0.00791611466666667, 
-0.00719977883333333, -0.0065441495, -0.00591280316666667, 
-0.00526931516666667, -0.00461368616666667, -0.00395805733333333, 
-0.00329028698333333, -0.00263465763333333, -0.00193046343333333, 
-0.00126269308333333, -0.00063134655, -1.21412798333333e-05, 
0.0005463576, 0.00111699776666667, 0.00169977918333333, 0.00220971298333333, 
0.00269536395, 0.00316887395, 0.003642384, 0.00409161133333333, 
0.0044437085, 0.0048443705, 0.005172185, 0.00548785833333333, 
0.0057549665, 0.00598565083333333, 0.00624061783333333, 0.00639845466666667, 
0.00653200816666667, 0.00664128016666667, 0.00671412783333333, 
0.0067626925, 0.00678697583333333, 0.00678697583333333, 0.00676269316666667, 
0.00670198616666667, 0.00660485583333333, 0.00645916083333333, 
0.00630132416666667, 0.00604635716666667, 0.00577924883333333, 
0.0054999995, 0.005172185, 0.00478366416666667, 0.004383002, 
0.0040187635, 0.0035331125, 0.00303531981666667, 0.00253752743333333, 
0.00205187631666667, 0.00150551863333333, 0.000947019833333333, 
0.000376379673333333, -0.000230684318333333, -0.0008984547, 
-0.00154194248333333, -0.00219757163333333, -0.00287748321666667, 
-0.00353311226666667, -0.00421302416666667, -0.00486865333333333, 
-0.00552428216666667, -0.0062163355, -0.0068598235, -0.00753973483333333, 
-0.00824392883333333, -0.00891169966666667, -0.00951876366666667, 
-0.010186534, -0.010805739, -0.0114370858333333, -0.0120320083333333, 
-0.012639073, -0.0132218531666667, -0.0137803523333333, -0.0143388515, 
-0.0148245028333333, -0.0152980126666667, -0.0157108165, 
-0.0161479028333333, -0.0165485635, -0.0169249445, -0.0172770415, 
-0.0176048558333333, -0.0179083875, -0.0181147896666667, 
-0.0183576146666667, -0.0185397348333333, -0.018697571, -0.0188189831666667, 
-0.0188918313333333, -0.0189525373333333, -0.0190011033333333, 
-0.0189768206666667, -0.0189768206666667, -0.0189525386666667, 
-0.0188432665, -0.0187461363333333, -0.0185761588333333, 
-0.0183211913333333, -0.0180783656666667, -0.0178112581666667, 
-0.0174713018333333, -0.0171070633333333, -0.0167306835, 
-0.0163178798333333, -0.0158565118333333, -0.0154072848333333, 
-0.0149459155, -0.0144359823333333, -0.0138653411666667, 
-0.0132825598333333, -0.0126876383333333, -0.0120320083333333, 
-0.0114613678333333, -0.0107935976666667, -0.0101986748333333, 
-0.00953090416666667, -0.00892384083333333, -0.00824392883333333, 
-0.00755187583333333, -0.0068476815, -0.00622847633333333, 
-0.00551214116666667, -0.00488079433333333, -0.00423730666666667, 
-0.0035452535, -0.00291390716666667, -0.00223399545, -0.00156622503333333, 
-0.000934878566666667, -0.000267108155, 0.000291390715, 0.00084988955, 
0.00142052971666667, 0.00197902856666667, 0.00244039716666667, 
0.00295033088333333, 0.003435982, 0.0038852095, 0.00428587166666667, 
0.0046622515, 0.00502648983333333, 0.005342163, 0.0056335535, 
0.0058885205, 0.00608278116666667, 0.00630132416666667, 0.0064470195, 
0.00656843216666667, 0.00667770383333333, 0.00671412766666667, 
0.0067626925, 0.00676269316666667, 0.00677483416666667, 0.00672626866666667, 
0.00664128016666667, 0.00653200816666667, 0.0063620305, 0.00611920466666667, 
0.00587637933333333, 0.00560927116666667, 0.00528145666666667, 
0.004953642, 0.00454083866666667, 0.00415231766666667, 0.0037030905, 
0.00324172168333333, 0.00274392916666667, 0.00224613676666667, 
0.00173620305, 0.00118984546666667, 0.0006192053, 1.214128e-05, 
-0.000582781433333333, -0.00123841056666667, -0.0019061809, 
-0.00258609256666667, -0.00322958058333333, -0.0039216335, 
-0.00457726266666667, -0.005257174, -0.00591280316666667, 
-0.0065320085, -0.00727262683333333, -0.00796467966666667, 
-0.00864459116666667, -0.00928807916666667, -0.00990728416666667, 
-0.0105629131666667, -0.0111942596666667, -0.0118013241666667, 
-0.0123841055, -0.0130033101666667, -0.0135496686666667, 
-0.0140838846666667, -0.0146181005, -0.0150916111666667, 
-0.0155165561666667, -0.0159657828333333, -0.0163785865, 
-0.0167792476666667, -0.0171192046666667, -0.0174591603333333, 
-0.017774834, -0.018066225, -0.0182604846666667, -0.0184668873333333, 
-0.0186490056666667, -0.0187704185, -0.0188675491666667, 
-0.0189525373333333, -0.0190011033333333, -0.0190253848333333, 
-0.019013244, -0.0189889613333333, -0.0189161133333333, -0.0188189838333333, 
-0.0186732876666667, -0.0184547455, -0.0182119198333333, 
-0.0179690948333333, -0.017629138, -0.0172891835, -0.0169128038333333, 
-0.0165364226666667, -0.0160750548333333, -0.0156258271666667, 
-0.0151765998333333, -0.0146666665, -0.01413245, -0.0135375268333333, 
-0.0129668866666667, -0.0123355401666667, -0.0117284768333333, 
-0.0111092713333333, -0.0104779245, -0.0098708605, -0.00920309, 
-0.0085231785, -0.0078311255, -0.00715121416666667), loop = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", 
"36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", 
"47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", 
"58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", 
"69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", 
"80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", 
"91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", 
"101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", 
"110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", 
"119", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", 
"128", "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136", 
"137", "138", "139", "140", "141", "142", "143", "144", "145", 
"146", "147", "148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", 
"155", "156", "157", "158", "159", "160", "161", "162", "163", 
"164", "165", "166", "167", "168", "169", "170", "171", "172", 
"173", "174", "175", "176", "177", "178", "179", "180", "181", 
"182", "183", "184", "185", "186", "187", "188", "189", "190", 
"191", "192", "193", "194", "195", "196", "197", "198", "199", 
"200", "201", "202", "203", "204", "205", "206", "207", "208", 
"209", "210", "211", "212", "213", "214", "215", "216", "217", 
"218", "219", "220", "221", "222", "223", "224", "225", "226", 
"227", "228", "229", "230", "231", "232", "233", "234", "235", 
"236", "237", "238", "239", "240", "241", "242", "243", "244", 
"245", "246", "247", "248", "249", "250", "251", "252", "253", 
"254", "255", "256", "257", "258", "259", "260", "261", "262", 
"263", "264", "265", "266", "267", "268", "269", "270", "271", 
"272", "273", "274", "275", "276", "277", "278", "279", "280", 
"281", "282", "283", "284", "285", "286", "287", "288", "289", 
"290", "291", "292", "293", "294", "295", "296", "297", "298", 
"299", "300", "301", "302", "303", "304", "305", "306", "307", 
"308", "309", "310", "311", "312", "313", "314", "315", "316", 
"317", "318", "319", "320", "321", "322", "323", "324", "325", 
"326", "327", "328", "329", "330", "331", "332", "333", "334", 
"335", "336", "337", "338", "339", "340", "341", "342", "343", 
"344", "345", "346", "347", "348", "349", "350", "351", "352", 
"353", "354", "355", "356", "357", "358", "359", "360", "361", 
"362"), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to write a function that first groups the data by loops by the row numbers.

There are three loops of data provided for this sample data frame as shown:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(Rotation, Actuator.Force)) + 
  geom_path(aes(group = as.factor(loop), colour = as.factor(loop))) +
  labs(colour = "Loops")
```

[image]

The original data does not have the `loop` column and I need a function that would group the data by loops.

The definition of a loop is all the points from the beginning of the data all the way to the maximum x, back to the minimum x and right before it reaches the starting x point of the loop.

The desired output is a function that would produce the `loop` column based on the `Rotation` and `Actuator.Force` columns.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really have anything to do with plotting per se. Taking inspiration from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/61032), you can calculate the period of your data and try to use that to estimate the loop. In the example below, I only use the `Rotation` data and get 1 mismatch between the estimated loop and the actual loop, which I'm OK with.

```r
# Use spectrum methods to estimate period
ssp <- spectrum(df$Rotation, plot = FALSE, method = "ar", n.freq = 1e4)
period <- 1 / with(ssp, freq[spec == max(spec)])

# How many full periods can I fit in my rows (+ 1)
estimate <- (seq_len(nrow(df)) %/% period) + 1

table(estimate, loop = df$loop)
#>         loop
#> estimate   1   2   3
#>        1 121   0   0
#>        2   1 120   0
#>        3   0   0 120
```

I don't know how well this generalises to whatever other periodic data.