# Group periodic data in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I have a dataset comprised of periodic data. I want to group the data by period.
The full dataset is provided: [LINK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1497hrm0Ory-FHeuPEge1jfqwXCIjlo79/view?usp=sharing)
Data for one period of the dataset is provided and ploted:

```
> dput(DATA[1:122,c(2,9)])
structure(list(Actuator.Force = c(-4853.5854, -4566.9771, -4198.7612, 
-3774.5527, -3317.6958, -2847.5229, -2364.7585, -1880.9485, -1405.4272, 
-930.289, -467.04822, -18.867363, 421.17499, 838.86719, 1239.9121, 
1626.0669, 1990.6389, 2334.0852, 2655.344, 2962.0227, 3243.7817, 
3506.2249, 3744.2622, 3959.8271, 4156.7061, 4324.9048, 4469.229, 
4591.6689, 4687.4194, 4764.0801, 4814.6167, 4840.313, 4846.0181, 
4826.3135, 4777.6553, 4696.0791, 4583.854, 4442.457, 4272.5254, 
4076.7224, 3851.1211, 3603.1853, 3330.7456, 3038.3157, 2724.115, 
2386.5476, 2032.5809, 1660.0547, 1268.0084, 859.16675, 432.4075, 
-14.131592, -479.29309, -955.67108, -1444.614, -1937.2562, -2437.0085, 
-2941.8914, -3450.9009, -3959.9597, -4468.9795, -4981.2549, -5492.6997, 
-6002.334, -6510.5425, -7016.2432, -7517.8286, -8013.1348, -8500.4199, 
-8974.8867, -9439.5479, -9890.5938, -10326.367, -10744.421, -11147.754, 
-11534.83, -11902.651, -12248.997, -12577.919, -12885.458, -13172.309, 
-13441.554, -13691.502, -13922.634, -14127.116, -14305.272, -14458.267, 
-14582.934, -14685.274, -14758.539, -14806.058, -14830.719, -14836.625, 
-14822.204, -14773.916, -14700.484, -14597.968, -14469.834, -14312.099, 
-14126.422, -13915.136, -13676.505, -13412.388, -13120.703, -12807.961, 
-12473.883, -12115.751, -11740.082, -11342.633, -10929.945, -10502.158, 
-10062.869, -9611.8271, -9146.6006, -8673.3545, -8191.7417, -7700.769, 
-7200.9346, -6695.8809, -6185.2378, -5670.8711, -5154.9995),
Rotation = c(-0.005985651, -0.00565783616666667, -0.00522075016666667, 
-0.0046743925, -0.00406732866666667, -0.00343598223333333, 
-0.00286534205, -0.00219757165, -0.00156622503333333, -0.000934878566666667, 
-0.000267108158333333, 0.000303531998333333, 0.00084988955, 
0.0013962471, 0.00193046351666667, 0.00242825596666667, 0.00288962463333333, 
0.0033995583, 0.0038366445, 0.00424944783333333, 0.004637969, 
0.0050507725, 0.005378587, 0.00565783616666667, 0.00594922716666667, 
0.00620419383333333, 0.006410596, 0.0065684325, 0.00670198666666667, 
0.00683554116666667, 0.0069205295, 0.00699337683333333, 0.0070055185, 
0.006993377, 0.00696909483333333, 0.00688410516666667, 0.006774834, 
0.00659271483333333, 0.006386313, 0.00613134633333333, 0.0058399555, 
0.0055364235, 0.00518432633333333, 0.00483222916666667, 0.0044072845, 
0.00403090483333333, 0.00353311216666667, 0.0029988961, 0.00251324506666667, 
0.0020275938, 0.00144481233333333, 0.00086203085, 0.000303531998333333, 
-0.000315673273333333, -0.000983443666666667, -0.00162693151666667, 
-0.00233112578333333, -0.0029988961, -0.00366666666666667, 
-0.00433443683333333, -0.00496578316666667, -0.00563355366666667, 
-0.0062770415, -0.0069690945, -0.0076611475, -0.00836534183333333, 
-0.00902097083333333, -0.00968874116666667, -0.0103443703333333, 
-0.0109514346666667, -0.011594922, -0.012177704, -0.0127969093333333, 
-0.0133918318333333, -0.0139746131666667, -0.0145209698333333, 
-0.014982339, -0.0154437081666667, -0.0159050765, -0.0163178798333333, 
-0.0167185421666667, -0.0170706398333333, -0.0174105943333333, 
-0.0177505506666667, -0.018017659, -0.0182483433333333, -0.0184547455, 
-0.0186490056666667, -0.0187704183333333, -0.01887969, -0.0189525386666667, 
-0.018988962, -0.0190011033333333, -0.018988962, -0.0189768206666667, 
-0.0189282553333333, -0.0188189838333333, -0.018673289, -0.018442604, 
-0.0182240605, -0.017993377, -0.0176534206666667, -0.0173256068333333, 
-0.0169492263333333, -0.0165485635, -0.0161357608333333, 
-0.0156622516666667, -0.0152373058333333, -0.0147152313333333, 
-0.0141931568333333, -0.0136103748333333, -0.0130275935, 
-0.0123962468333333, -0.0118013235, -0.0112064015, -0.0105507718333333, 
-0.00993156683333333, -0.0092637965, -0.008620309, -0.00791611466666667, 
-0.00719977883333333, -0.0065441495)), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", 
"36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", 
"47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", 
"58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", 
"69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", 
"80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", 
"91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", 
"101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", 
"110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", 
"119", "120", "121", "122"), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

The next row of the data starts a new period and so on. I want to group the rows by the periods that exist in the data.

Although the code provided in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67218024/function-to-count-the-number-of-loops-in-data-and-group-them-in-r) can find the periods if fully completed data is provided (it worked for the first three periods), when applied to the entire dataset of periodic data, it resulted in `NaN`s.

```
ssp <- spectrum(DATA$Rotation, plot = FALSE, method = "ar", n.freq = 1e6)
period <- 1 / with(ssp, freq[spec == max(spec)])

DATA$Loop <- (seq_len(nrow(DATA)) %/% period) + 1
```

Comment: Would it suffice to count it as a new period each time Rotation moves in the positive direction past -0.006?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach where I define a region where both the Rotation is increasing and Rotation is at least as high as the starting value. Then I count how many times we enter that region and that's the period number.

```
library(dplyr)
Rot_start = DATA$Rotation[1]
rbind(DATA, DATA) %>%  # to demonstrate two cycles
  mutate(Rot_pos = Rotation > lag(Rotation, default = -1),
         Rot_rightside = Rotation >= Rot_start,
         Rot_region = Rot_pos & Rot_rightside,
         new_period = Rot_region & !(lag(Rot_region, default = FALSE)),
         period = cumsum(new_period))

  # more succinct, same workings
  # mutate(Rot_region = Rotation > lag(Rotation, default = -1) & Rotation >= Rot_start,
  #        period = cumsum(Rot_region & !(lag(Rot_region, default = FALSE))))
```